# What can these verbs be called as a group?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary, lexicon, collocations

I'm going to teach my students about different patterns of usage of these verbs: marry (e.g. get married, marry sb, marry to), die (e.g. die of , die from, die for), match (e.g. match (something), match somebody/something (to/with somebody/something), agree (agree with something, agree (with somebody) (about/on something), agree to something). I'm not sure what they should be called. Do anyone have suggestions?

Comment: They're often called subcategorisation frames in linguistics, but language teachers probably have other terminology. You should probably ask at the [languagelearning.se] instead.

Comment: If you need a term that's not just random, "verb frames" is easy to remember and gives a good idea what it's  about, IMHO. I think in linguistics this is not generally seen as a type of verb, rather as the ways just about any verb can be used in a sentence. I guess there are verbs maybe that can only be used in one way and that's it, but they'd likely be a minority.

Comment: See 'affordance'?

Comment: Just curious, what do you think these verbs have in common to justify putting them together into one group?

Comment: Pretty much every verb in English has its own syntactic and lexical peculiarities; its affordances, its prohibitions, its licenses. Some take complements, of certain kinds only; others require objects or forbid them. There are some regularities, with certain rules like the [_Spray/Load_ Alternation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/spray.pdf), for instance. All the verbs in that particular verb class ([one of many](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/levin.verbs2.txt) in Levin's _English Verb Classes and Alternations_) allow both _He loaded the truck with beer_ and _He loaded beer on the truck_.

Comment: It is not just a question of valency. He/she asks for something more complex. In the phenomena raised by these examples, there is also the diathesis (marry/get married), the phrasal verb (die of). There is no one term to describe all.

Answer (score 1):

These are called "verb frames" or "subcategorisation frames". In English, one frame has many verbs in it, and one verb may belong to many frames.